# Meaning of “man” in “Wie schreibt man Ihren Namen?”

Tags: grammar, meaning, pronoun

> Wie schreibt man Ihren Namen?

I understand the grammar of the above sentence except the word *man.*
What is the meaning of *man?* Can we omit it, so it would be the following?

> Wie schreibt Ihren Namen?

Comment: A look into a dictionary would explain you the meaning of "man". A look into a grammar would not be wrong.

Comment: `man` in `Wie schreibt man Ihren Namen?` is like `you` in `How do you write your name?`

Comment: @Fantômas: a closer resemblance would be `How does one write your name?` and like in that English version, the subject man/one cannot be just omitted (`How does write your name?`)

Comment: @cbeleites Well, it's quite the same... You can't omit `you` in `How do you write your name?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Man](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-man.html?lang=en)

The German *man* is an [indefinite pronoun](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-Indefinit.html?MenuId=Word426) replacing a not further specified person or group of persons in a sentence. It only exists in nominative singular and replaces the (essential) subject of your example sentence:

> Wie schreiben **die Leute** Ihren Namen? - Wie schreibt **man** Ihren Namen?

Personal pronouns have a similar function but they are inflected:

> Wie schreibst **du** deinen Namen? Wie schreiben **Sie** Ihren Namen? Wie schreibe **ich** Ihren Namen?

Comment: If you convert to passive voice, "man" disappears into thin air: "Wie wird Ihr Name geschrieben?"

Comment: Another way to avoid "man" is to use the reflexive pronoun: "Wie schreibt sich ihr Name?"

Comment: @RHa or "Wie wird Ihr Name geschrieben?"

Answer (score 4):

The word "man" is the subject of the sentence. "Man" is the one who writes, and besides the verb itself this is actually the one thing you cannot omit in that sentence. 
The closest English equivalent to "man" is "one", more idiomatic options are "you" and "people", depending on context.